# How to select rows if it only existed after a specific date?

Tags: sql

How do I select rows if the data exists after a specified date? For example, I want to find the revenue when the TIN wasn't in the database before 2017. And if the TIN was in the database before 2017, I don't want to pull the revenue in the previous years.

For example, this pulls all the revenue, and doesn't take into consideration whether or not there was data associated with the TIN prior.

```
SELECT [DateRevenueAccrued]
  ,[TIN]
  ,[Net Revenue]
FROM [CSTM].[reports].[IncomeNew]
WHERE DateRevenueAccrued > '1/1/2017'
```

Comment: It doesn't look like MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT [DateRevenueAccrued], [TIN], [Net Revenue]
FROM [CSTM].[reports].[IncomeNew] i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [CSTM].[reports].[IncomeNew] i2
                  WHERE i2.TIN = i.TIN AND
                        DateRevenueAccrued < '2017-01-01'
                  );
```

Comment: this is much faster 

Comment: I am confused by the addition of the "i".

Comment: That is a table alias, an important part of the SQL language.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below if the question is TIN 
 exists/not exists though this is row by row

```
       SELECT REVENUE FROM TABLE 
      WHERE (DateRevenueAccrued < 
      '1/1/2017' AND TIN IS NULL )OR
        (DateRevenueAccrued >=
      '1/1/2017')
```